# Traffic Manager shows "Stopped" for Web App at Basic plan

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

Today I was doing some experiments with the new Traffic Manager (new azure portal). I configured a new Azure Traffic Manager and added an Azure Website endpoint. But the Traffic Manager endpoint status says Status of the endpoint as "Stopped" where the Web app is up and running. Also the Azure Traffic Manager Monitoring status is Inactive. I am confused. I did this few times and still getting the same result.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Traffic Manager is only eligible for use with App Services (formerly known as Azure Websites and Azure Mobile Services) at the 'Standard' level or above.  If you downgrade your App Service to the Free or Basic tiers, it shows as 'stopped' in Traffic Manager (this is somewhat misleading and we are working to improve the experience).

Mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-endpoint-types/#web-apps-as-endpoints).

Comment: I also figured this out after I was trying it with the classic portal where it shows a warning message saying only standard websites will be monitored.  It would be nice to have at least a warning message. Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Does not look good to me. Why this is so? We can point at an external resource without additional charges so why this pointing requires extra charge?